# ImageView not clickable while secondary thread is running

Tags: android

I am trying to do an ImageView not clickable while another thread is running. Then when thread finish then bring back the ImageView clickable again.

Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ...    
   imageView.setClickeable(false); // or setEnabled = false

   new Thread(){
      public void run(){
         anotherClass.secondClassMethod();
      }
   }.start();

   imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {            
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         ...
      }
    });
}


private anotherClassCallback callback = new anotherClassCallback(){

   @Override
   public void hasFinished(){
      imageView.setClickable(true); // or setEnabled = true
   }
};
```

But it is Actually not working because, for example, if I click 3 times on imageView while thread is running, when hasFinished method executes then it looks like it kept my 3 clicks and then runs 3 onTouch straightaway.

Does someone know whats happening?

Thx u!

Comment: try imageView.setOnClickListener(null); insdie run method. once run method completes, then add the listener.

Comment: You should use asynctask instead of thread.
As mentioned in answer bellow you should use setOnclickListener instead of setOntouchListener.

new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
    onPreExectute(){
         imageView.setClickeable(false);
    }


}.execute();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onTouch and onClick are not the same, so when you are setting onClickable false touch events are still fired. Maybe try doing what you are doing in setOnClickListener()

Comment: You are right, but I need to use onTouch because my app musn't play "click" when you touch the imageView (a requirement of my app).

Comment: In that case i'd do what kumar said but for onTouchListener. Basically set it to false when you start your thread, if I understand what you are trying to do. You can also use var or something to keep track if it should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should use asynctask instead of thread.
As mentioned in answer bellow you should use setOnclickListener instead of setOntouchListener.

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
    onPreExectute(){
         imageView.setClickeable(false);
         imageView.setOnclickListener(null);
    }

    doInBackround(){

    }

    onPostExecute(){
         imageView.setClickeable(true);
         imageView.setOnclickListener(new OnclickListener(){
         onClick(View v){

         }
         });
    }


}.execute();
```

Comment: I changed it but it's still not working. It looks like is keeping the clicks and then running them straightaway when onPostExecute is executed (and imageView.setOnclickListener(...) executed then).